# How to show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}^3 \textbf{k} \frac {e^{i \textbf{k x}}} {(2 \pi)^3} = \delta^3(x)$ in spherical coordinates?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Recently I had to deal with Fourier transformations and delta functions, and I was wondering how about that. I know, that its trivial to show in cartesian coordinates, but i couldn't do it in spherical coordinates. Somehow one should be able to reduce it to something which only depends on |k| (which i could do) and show that it is a delta function (which i couldn't).

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you know the expression for the delta-function you use in spherical coordinates or do you want to derive this? I suspect you are looking for a derivation of the result $\delta^3({\bf x}) \equiv \delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z) = \frac{\delta(r)}{2\pi r^2}$ where $r=|{\bf x}|$ and where the latter function is the delta function in spherical coordinates.

Comment: The result mentioned above is shown [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398777/dirac-delta-in-polar-coordinates) for polar coordinates. The approach used to get the result is the same for spherical coordinates, i.e. you need to calculate the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation.

Comment: Depends, what you mean with 'the expression for the delta-function you use in spherical coordinates'.
I already know that this is a delta function since I know that this is $\delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z)= \frac{\delta(\textbf{r})}{2 \pi r^2}$.
But lets assume, that I don't know, that this Integral is a delta function, and I only know how to integrate in spherical coordinates.

I take coordinates where x is along the z-axis.
So I have to do the integration over $\phi$ (which is trivial), $\theta$ (which should give me $2 \frac{sin(kx)}{kx}$, but maybe this is wrong) and $k$.

Comment: You might try to first derive something like $\delta({\bf x}) \propto \int_0^\infty {\rm d}k\,k^2 \frac{\sin(kx)}{kx} = \frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^\infty {\rm d}k\,(e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx})$. For a spherically symmetric function $f({\bf x}) = f(x)$ then try integrating $\int\delta({\bf x})f(x) {\rm d}^3x \propto \int_0^\infty{\rm d x} xf(x)\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^\infty {\rm d}k (e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx})$ by parts to 'see this'. If this calculation makes sense is another question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ in the last integral?
Nevertheless, this is exactly the point, where i got stuck.
Let's say, the integral $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}k ~cos(kx)$ does vanish (in some sense), then we are still left with the equation
$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} \int_0^\infty  \mathrm{d}k~ cos(kx)=f(0)$
but this doesn't make sense, if we already assumed that the integral over k vanishes for all x

Comment: When considering the 3D Dirac delta distribution $\delta^3({\bf x})$ using coordinates, one should use a coordinate system that is defined in an open neighborhood of the support $\{{\bf 0}\}$ of the distribution. Spherical coordinates fail in that department.

Comment: Do I understand you right, that the problem is, that for k=0 the coordinates are not well defined? But why does then the formula $\delta(x) \delta(y) \delta(z) =\frac{ \delta(r)}{2 \pi r^2}$ exist?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to start and work with any kind of co-ordinates in here, it can be done only using Delta & Fourier transform properties, as follows:

First, take a look at the fourier transform of the delta:
$$\mathcal{F}[\delta^3(\textbf{x})] = \int \mathrm{d}^3 \textbf{x} \delta^3(\textbf{x}) {e^{-i \textbf{kx}}} = 1$$ Now use the fact that the inverse fourier transform of fourier transform of some function (assume you can apply the transform) is the function+use the result above and the definition of inverse transform to obtain:
$$\delta^3(\textbf{x})=\mathcal{F^{-1}}[\mathcal{F[\delta^3(\textbf{x})]}]=\mathcal{F^{-1}}[1]= \int \mathrm{d}^3 \textbf{k} \frac {e^{i \textbf{k x}}} {(2 \pi)^3} $$