# How to express the concentrated Force at the center of a circular domain into a distributed pressure with the help of Dirac Delta?

Tags: dirac-delta

**Background: the beam case (1D)**
[image]

For a beam bearing concentrated froce $P$ at the middle, the concentrated force $P$ can be expressed in a distributed manner, i.e.,
$$
q=P\delta(r)
$$
such that the line integration
$$
\int_{-L}^Lqdx=P
$$

---

**The circular plate case (2D with axisymmetry)**

[image]

According to the accepted answer of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398777/dirac-delta-in-polar-coordinates), the concented force $P$ at the center of a circular plate can be expressed as
$$
q=\frac{P}{2\pi r}\delta(r)
$$
such that the area integration
$$
\int_0^Rq\bullet2\pi rdr =P\int_0^R \delta(r)dr=P
$$

But **I am confused about the value of $q$ in the domain $r\in [0,R]$**. Mathematica told me that
$$
q(r)=0,  {\forall} r {\in} [0,R]
$$

It's like that no pressure is applied on the surface of the plate, but somehow it is equivelant to a conentrated force at the center.
How to understand this?